# R web scraping: I can't pull up the elements I want

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm a beginner in web scraping using R. I'm trying to scrape the following webpage: https://bkmea.com/bkmea-members/#/company/2523.

I would like to get all text elements under `div` nodes with `class="company_name"`, as well as text elements under `td` nodes. For example, I'm trying to fetch the company name ("MOMO APPARELS") as in the following HTML text.

```
<div class="comapny_header">
    <div class="company_name">MOMO APPARELS LTD</div> 
    <div class="view_all">View All</div>
</div>
```

So I've written the following code:

```
library(textreadr)
library(rvest)

companyinfo <- read_html("https://bkmea.com/bkmea-members/#/company/2523")

html_nodes(companyinfo,"div")%>% 
  html_text()  # it works

html_nodes(companyinfo,"div.company_name")%>% 
  html_text()  # doesn't work 

html_nodes(companyinfo,"td") %>% 
  html_text()  # doesn't work
```

If I understand correctly - the first one should pull up texts with `div` nodes.
The second one should pull up texts within `div` nodes with attributes equal to `company_name`.
The third one should pull up texts within `td` nodes.

The first one works (which isn't what I'm trying to get) but the second and the third ones don't - am I doing something terribly wrong?

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out here!!

Many thanks,
Sang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're looking for is retrieved by this API (it is not present in the html body) :

```sh
GET https://bkmea.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bkmea_get_company&id=2523
```

You just need to extract the `id` from your original url, build the url above and parse json result as following :

```
library(httr)

originalUrl <- "https://bkmea.com/bkmea-members/#/company/2523"
id <- sub("^.+/", "", originalUrl)
userAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"

output <- content(GET("https://bkmea.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", query = list(
        "action" = "bkmea_get_company",
        "id" = id
    ), add_headers('User-Agent' = userAgent)), as = "parsed", type = "application/json")

print(output$company$company_info$company_name)
```

output :

```
[1] "MOMO APPARELS LTD"
```

Comment: Thank you! This works magically and gets exactly what I want. Perhaps another embarrassing question as a beginner: for any webpage how can I possibly know if the data is being retrieved by an API? I couldn't find the url in the html text.. Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: @SanghyunPark you can open the developer tool, go to network tab/response tab and check the html. Also in this case it takes quite a long time to load the data inside the page, whereas the page has already been loaded. The API endpoint can be spotted by checking the result and looking for json result (or other human readable format)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know how to accept the answer. I just accepted it. Thank you so much for your help!